# An easy way to remove all children in a parent-child relation?

Tags: objects

I have some parent-child relations with the Blender objects that I'm working with, to make the things cleaner. Now I have an object with all its children that I don't want any more, the object specifically is an empty and the children are some meshes, there are a bunch of them and I'm looking for an easy and fast way to delete them all to avoid select them one-by-one. Maybe some python script?

Comment: this may be a bit over-simplified and context specific but, since its just an empty, couldn't you just delete the empty? (then add a new one)

Comment: Deleting the empty moves its children to the parent node, but not delete them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the parent object, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *> Children* to select all the children automatically.

You can then remove the parent-child relationships acting upon all selected objects by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

See the [official docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting) on parenting

Comment: Using that method is a two-step process, because you first delete all the children and then the parent. But it's fine, is pretty much better than deleting them one-by-one. Thanks

Comment: see my edit for details on simply removing the parent-child relationship

Comment: its says my edit need to be reviewed... you can remove parent child relationships with alt-p

Comment: The edit is somewhat redundant, once you select the objects (and delete them as OP wants), the relationships are destroyed.

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen I already checked the official docs before asking, Alt-p just _removes the relation_ this means that the child will be disassociated from the parent, but not deleted

Comment: @lordscales91 oh im sorry... it sounded like you wanted to delete the relationships, not the objects themselves... to that end i dont believe there is a single hotkey to delete the children of a selected parent as this is not a common enough task, and it only requires a second step to accomplish... you could however examine the source for these hotkeys, and create your own addon if you know python